# Accessing variable from within method

Tags: php, class

Assuming the following class

```
class test {

public $x = 2;

public testFunction() {

//...

}

}
```

Is there any way I can access $x from within testFunction()?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, simply using `$this->x`

You may wish to brush up on [PHP's OOP principles](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Comment: Can I do it even if $x = new OtherClass()? Because I seem to get an error there...

Comment: If `$x` is a property of `test`, but is an `instance` of another class this is still perfectly valid. Perhaps consider posting another question with a paste of your new code and the error message you receive.